# How to make this grid system on Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

See the picture first:

[image]

Now I have 1 row with 4 columns (col-md-3): 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 are elements that now are 6, but in a future will can be more (10, 12...), and "filter" is an affix div (when scroll, keeps on top).

The problem is: when I add 4, 5 and 6 elements, don't be positioned like in the picture, the red box in the picture, doesn't grow...

I don't want 2 rows (1 row for 1, 2 and 3 and other row for 4, 5 and 6).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution

```html
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8" style="background:red">
    <div class="col-md-3" style="background:purple">
      <div style="background:yellow; height:100px; border:solid black 3px"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" style="background:purple">
      <div style="background:yellow; height:100px; border:solid black 3px"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" style="background:purple">
      <div style="background:yellow; height:100px; border:solid black 3px"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" style="background:purple">
      <div style="background:yellow; height:100px; border:solid black 3px"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" style="background:purple">
      <div style="background:yellow; height:100px; border:solid black 3px"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4" style="background:blue">
    <div style="background:orange; height:150px; border:solid black 3px"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```